# Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed

Tags: vba, excel

I've been looking at this for ages now and I know its something simple.

the code below is throwing me an error "Method 'PasteSpecial' of object 'Range' failed" is the error

```
With xlWB.Sheets("Lookups")
    'Copy lookups tab to word test tables
    .Cells.Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Word_Test_Tables").Cells.PasteSpecial
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End With
```

The error occurs on the pastespecial.

Once this error has happened the code will continue to f5 through but nothing will actually happen, I can not select any tabs or workbooks and have to end task the application.

Putting a break point on the error line I can get a range from

```
?ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Word_Test_Tables").Cells
```

I have tried activating the sheet, unhiding the sheet. I can confirm xlWB is valid and open, .cells.copy looks to be working as you get the highlighting round the sheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why you would copy all the cells rather than just the used range:

```
    xlWB.Sheets("Lookups").Usedrange.copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Word_Test_Tables").Range("A1")
```

Comment: For some reason this worked perfectly. The sheets are exactly the same so I dont know why this would be ok and my code would not. I tried using .usedrange.copy in the with like my original code and that worked too, must be to do with .cells? any thoughts as to why?

Comment: Are both workbooks the same format? (i.e. not copying from an xlsx to an xls or vice versa?)

Comment: That should be fine then. Any merged cells, or hidden rows/columns? It could just be the sheer number of cells you are copying.

Comment: their are merged cells but no hidden rows/columns. unfortunately I cant get rid of the merged cells, think they may be the problem? I know that they can be a pain. If so maybe I could clear all the formatting on the destination sheet before pasting? Data range it is coping is A1:DN424 so it is not massive

Comment: I'd just stick with the `usedrange` version.

Comment: O I will, was just curious for my own learning. Thanks for the fix anyway

Comment: Out of interest, does this work: `xlWB.Sheets("Lookups").Cells.copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Word_Test_Tables").Range("A1")`

Comment: That does not. actually got a different error got the one about "object invoked has disconnected from its clients" then on F5 got the "Copy method of Range class failed"

Answer (score 0):

You need to come out of your 'with' to paste the values in the other workbook:

```
With xlWB.Sheets("Lookups")
'Copy lookups tab to word test tables
.Cells.Copy

End With

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Word_Test_Tables").Cells.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: Got the same error with the above. As far as I am aware you should be able to do the above within the with as long as you dont use the "." from the with you'll be good.

Comment: Okay, that's strange though as I tested the code before posting and it ran fine? Is there more to the code that you haven't included?

Comment: Although I think @Rory has probably the best solution using usedRange?

Comment: For arguments sake I used the same code as I originally posted with the .usedrange rather than .cells and it worked fine. The sheets are exactly the same so cant see why .cells wouldnt work but hey ho it works :). There is lots to the code that is not included and to post a bigger snippet would be thousands of lines of code but this is the only parts that regard the sheet"Lookups"

Answer (score 0):

You may have worksheets with different sizes depending on the source workbooks. Try copying a smaller `Range`.

Besides, you probably want `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`.

Comment: A smaller range as it appears would have fixed my problem. Even tho the sheets are the same, exactly the same. activeworkbook would be the data sheet so I would need Thisworkbook. Thanks for the answer.